# SwiftData: "Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = \"MyModel\"; desired type = NSManagedObject; given type = NSManagedObject;

Tags: ios, swift, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

I'm using SwiftData and have a Siri Shortcut that inserts a new model.

When I open the App after having used the Shortcut and perform something that creates a relationship for the new model that just got inserted, the App crashes and I'm getting this error:

`"Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = \"MyModel\"; desired type = NSManagedObject; given type = NSManagedObject;`

It sounds to me like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597981/unacceptable-type-of-value-for-to-one-relationship-property-user-desired-t) is related. The problem there seems to be having two core data stacks in memory at once. Only I don't see how the `CoreData` solution there could be applied to `SwiftData` (if it even is related).

Is there any way to "kill" the context that the Shortcut used after it finished? Or any other way to fix this issue?

Here are the basic parts:

**Shortcut**

```
struct MyAppIntent: AppIntent {
    // ...

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
          let schema = Schema([MyModel.self])
          let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(
              for: schema,
              configurations: ModelConfiguration(
                schema: schema,
                isStoredInMemoryOnly: false
              )
          )
           let task = Task.detached {
              let actor = MyActor(modelContainer: modelContainer)
              try await actor.doSomething()
          }
          try await task.value
          return .result()
    }
}
```

**Actor**

```
@ModelActor actor MyActor {
    func doSomething() {
        modelContext.insert(MyModel())
        try? modelContext.save()
    }
}
```

Setting up the ModelContainer inside the **App**

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        do {
            let schema = Schema([MyModel.self])
            return try ModelContainer(
                for: schema,
                configurations: ModelConfiguration(
                    schema: schema,
                    isStoredInMemoryOnly: false
                )
            )
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
@Model MyModel {
    // v Error: "Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship:..."
    @Relationship var someProp: OtherModel? 

    // ...
}
```

**Adding the relationship somewhere inside the App**

```
let someProp = OtherModel()
modelContext.insert(someProp)
myModel.someProp = someProp
try? modelContext.save()
```

Comment: Isn't the problem with duplicate ModelContainer objects rather than duplicate ModelContext since the ModelContainer is what corresponds to the stack?

Comment: In the code we can’t see are you using CoreData code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77370765/cant-convert-swiftdata-model-data-to-expected-argument-type-nsmanagedobject

Comment: @loremipsum I've added the part that inserts the model, I'm not sure if it's relevant as I've tried to do it in different ways and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't know much about the core issue, is there a certain solution that you have in mind that I could try? I know that I can have multiple `ModelContext`s and I can pass the `ModelContainer` across thread boundaries. It works as it should, the model shows up in the app and I can make changes to it. Only adding a relationship model is leading to a crash.

Comment: I got the impression that you are initialising a second ModelContainer which could be an issue if that is the case. Also I don't see how your example could be reproducible so it would help if you could provide a more complete example.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I added more context. I am indeed initialising a second `ModelContainer` for the Shortcut, is there another way to insert models from there?