# How do I access the SwiftData container from outside of SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

#### Accessing the container in SwiftUI

I'm setting up the SwiftData container in my App like this:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        do {
            let schema = Schema([MyModel.self])
            return try ModelContainer(
                for: schema,
                configurations: ModelConfiguration(
                    schema: schema,
                    isStoredInMemoryOnly: false
                )
            )
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
        .backgroundTask { ... }
    }
}
```

#### Accessing the container somewhere else:

I have a `.backgroundTask` and `AppIntent` that both access SwiftData.

Edit: for the `.backgroundTask` - as Joakim pointed out - I can simply pass-in the container:

```
.backgroundTask(.appRefresh("myTaskId")) {
    let container = await sharedModelContainer
    // ...
}
```

For the AppIntent I'm doing this:

```
struct MyAppIntent: AppIntent {
    // ...

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
          let schema = Schema([MyModel.self])
          let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(
              for: schema,
              configurations: ModelConfiguration(
                schema: schema,
                isStoredInMemoryOnly: false
              )
          )
           let task = Task.detached {
              let actor = MyActor(modelContainer: modelContainer)
              try await actor.doSomething()
          }
          try await task.value
          return .result()
    }
}
```

**Is that the correct way of accessing the ModelContainer from other places?**

Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/preserving-your-apps-model-data-across-launches) it seems to me like it is, but maybe I'm missing something.

---

The issue is when I open the App after having run the Shortcut or the background task and perform something that creates a relationship for a new model that just got inserted, the App crashes and [I'm getting this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78032827/swiftdata-unacceptable-type-of-value-for-to-one-relationship-property-mym):

> "Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "MyModel"; desired type = NSManagedObject; given type = NSManagedObject;

Comment: The ModelContainer conforms to Sendable so pass the original one to the background task rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ah you're right, the warning `Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'MyApp' in a '@Sendable' closure` was confusing me. How about the `AppIntent`, I'm guessing there's no way to pass it in there?

Comment: I don’t know much about AppIntent but if it’s separate from your app I assume you must create a new model container.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It's separate from the rest, yes. So the way it is looks like it's correct? Might be an iOS bug in that case

Comment: The configuration yes but you are creating it as a local variable  in an async function and then you pass it to your actor, I have no idea if this is an issue at all but normally you create it (and keep it) at a more global scope so you have one instance that exists as long as the app runs.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the problem is the `AppIntent` lives outside of the App (and can run whether or not the App is running, e.g. via Shortcut). Even if I don't use the actor and `ModelContext(container)` instead the issue is still there.